# savePlot function puts graphs into a larger blank grahical area. How to fix?

Tags: r, plot

When I use the savePlot function I get a graph inside a larger blank graph area. How can I stop this? The beauty of savePlot should be to save a graph for easy insert into Microsoft Word. Now I have to edit the graphs to remove excess. It is like seeing 2 out of 8 business cards placed in positions (1,1) and(2,1) on a page containing eight card places like a 4x2 matrix.

R code:

```
plot.new()
# set up the graphics
par(mfrow=c(2,1), omi=c(1, 1, 1, 1)) 
tsplot(soi, col = 4, ylab = "", main = "Southern Oscillation Index")
tsplot(rec, col = 4, ylab = "", main = "Recruitment")
savePlot("soi.emf","emf") 
dev.off()
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you uploaded the graph somewhere so we can see what you are getting. Is your result two plots side-by-side? It looks like you are setting up R to draw that, but then with `dev.set(dev.next())` you are moving to the next graphics device after only drawing one plot - so you'll be getting half a blank plot. It is not clear which graphics device you are using or when you open it. Usually you would expect code writing plots out to begin by opening a graphics device e.g. through calling  `png()`.

Comment: *"The beauty of savePlot should be to save a graph for easy insert into Microsoft Word."* Unfortunately, I doubt that the developers of base-R would agree with this.

Comment: Haven't tried it: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/crop-r-figures/ Also, this could be interesting fo you: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/74-margin-and-oma-cheatsheet.html

Comment: It looks like I should put a website I developed years ago somewhere online. Let me work on that. I could store graphs and other items there.

Comment: Does it still have large margins when viewed in mspaint or other program?  `shell("mspaint soi.emf")`

Comment: mspaint view contains large margins. I am not using the shell interface but opening the app in windows. It is like printing two out of eight possible business cards. That is what the overall "box" for the two graphs look like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, without seeing your output, or knowing precisely what you want. But can you try:

```r
library(astsa)
if (!require(devEMF)) {
    install.packages("devEMF")
}
devEMF::emf("soi.emf")
plot.new()
par(mfrow = c(2, 1)) # set up the graphics
tsplot(soi, col = 4, ylab = "", main = "Southern Oscillation Index")
tsplot(rec, col = 4, ylab = "", main = "Recruitment")
dev.off()
```

Output:

[image: soi.emf]

Edit: Now I realise that the dataset is included with the package, I have included the output. I have also added `plot.new()` just in case you were overwriting an old plot. Is this your intended output?

Comment: Result is two tsplots placed over and under each other. Unfortunately the data is missing from the graphs. I don't know why. Good idea though.

Comment: Do you not want one graph above the other? This is what `par(mfrow=c(2,1))` does: you are creating a plot with two rows and one column. If you want two separate plots, just change that to `par(mfrow=c(1,1))` and after the first plot add `dev.off(); devEMF::emf("soi2.emf")` .

As to why the data is missing though... impossible to say as you have not included the data with your post!

Comment: data set is included with astsa package

Comment: I did not realise that. I have updated the post with the output. Is this not what you get? Is this what you want?

Comment: SamR.  Yes that is exactly what I want to do. But in addition I want to write the same output to a file. The code below does that with extra space. plot.new()
par(mfrow = c(2, 1)) # set up the graphics
tsplot(soi, col = 4, ylab = "", main = "Southern Oscillation Index")
tsplot(rec, col = 4, ylab = "", main = "Recruitment")
savePlot("soi.emf","emf") 
dev.off()

Comment: Have you tried changing the line `par(mfrow=c(2,1))` to `par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))`?

Comment: Yes. That does not work.